# Quit Vim when Buffer has no name (not :wq or :q!)

Tags: vimrc, init.vim

There must be a way to change the `init.vim` / `.vimrc` so I can quit Vim **without** saving first (`:wq`) nor force quitting (`:q!`). But I only want that behaviour when the *Buffer* has **no** name.

Why? Because a lot of times I use Vim just temporary for example:

- As a calculator
- Clipboard Text Editor
- Get the Unicode Value of a Character
- Dec to Hex Converter
- Etc... The List is enormous colossal.

*I am getting tired of typing in `:q!` instead of just `:q`.* So any Ideas?

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's called the [buftype option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27buftype%27)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Which one of these 9 Options? It doesn't seem to fit my need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few variations on the `:help 'buftype'` theme suggested by Heptite. The idea is the opposite of that in Pixelbog's answer: instead of changing the behavior of `:q`, we change the nature of the first buffer, turning it into a sacrificial scratchpad.

### Shell alias

```
$ vim +set\ buftype=nofile
```

starts Vim as usual, with an empty buffer, but makes it a scratch buffer by setting the `buftype` option to `nofile`.

You can make it an alias:

```
alias vims="vim +set\ buftype=nofile"
```

and do `$ vims` when you want a Vim **s**cratchpad.

### Short Vim command

You can create a Vim command with a short mnemonic name:

```
" in ~/.vimrc
command S set buftype=nofile
```

and call that command at startup with:

```
$ vim +S
```

when you need a **s**cratchpad.

(I use that very method to edit my `vimrc`: `$ vim +EV`.)

### Check arguments at startup

You can tell Vim to set the option above if it was called without arguments (filenames):

```
" in ~/.vimrc
if !exists('g:did_scratchpad') && argc(-1) == 0
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    let g:did_scratchpad = 1
endif
```

which allows you to simply do `$ vim` to get a scratchpad. The first empty buffer is the only one that is treated as a scratchpad so you don't have to worry about losing work in files you might decide to edit normally.

FWIW, I think this one is cool and I will probably keep a variation of it for a while.

See `:help argc()`.

### Bonus

Here is a "scratchpad" command from my `vimrc`, that I use very often:

```
command! SC vnew | setlocal bufhidden=wipe buftype=nofile nobuflisted noswapfile
```

Comment: Very detailed and informative answer, thanks. But does anything speak against doing it with `:abbreviate`? Are there any disadvantages you can think of to change the behavior of `:q`? I am gonna try both ways for like a week and then I am gonna pick the better one :)

Comment: No, it's just two different ways to approach the same problem. By focusing a bit too much on your "command" problem you sort of narrow down the field of possible solutions to "command" solutions. Which is not problematic in and of itself, but still a good way to miss better solutions. My answer provides a different perspective: instead of focusing on the "command" problem I focused on the actual need from which the problem arose (using `$ vim` like a scratchpad), which allowed me to think a bit more outside the box.

Comment: I am gonna use both of our solutions for like a month more. Both have some flaws: For example I don't like your solution, because I often get thrown into an empty buffer without starting vim from the cli. An example is: `grep foo bar.txt | neovim -`. My solution has the flaw, that it doesn't allow you to forcefully quit (`:q!`) in an empty buffer, because it will get expanded into this: `:q!!`. So yeah I am gonna choose in 1 Month which one to pick^^

Comment: Hmm, I don't follow. `$ grep foo bar.txt | vim -` works just as I would expect it to work: it opens Vim with the output of `$ grep foo bar.txt` in the first buffer… which is not super useful but I don't see how it conflicts with your stated goal. If you hit `:q`, then Vim quits just like you asked. If you open other buffers, then `:q` works normally for those buffers.

Comment: ehmmmmmm.... tbh I have no Idea what my thought behind it was while writing this... My brain is really tired right now^^ You are absolutely right, so far there are no flaws with your approach^^ My bad^^

Answer (score 3):

If you set `'buftype'` to `nofile` the buffer will be considered a "scratch buffer" and you won't have to force quit on the buffer, but you also won't be able to write it if you want to save it.

Comment: Yeah but whats the point of it? Isn't writing `bt=nofile` way longer than just putting the `!` after `:q`?^^

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> q (bufname('%') == '' ? 'q!' : 'q')
```

### Explanation

- You can simply use `:abbreviate` for this. Even better: `:cnoreabbrev`.
- Now you only need to check if the *Buffer* has a *name* or not. Do with a simple `if-statement`

Looks then like this:

```
function! QuitIfUnnamed()
    if bufname('%') == ''
        execute 'q!'
    else
        execute 'q'
    endif
endfunction

cnoreabbrev <expr> q QuitIfUnnamed()
```

And now if you want it to only have a `one-liner`, you can use a `ternary operator` and it would look like this:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> q (bufname('%') == '' ? 'q!' : 'q')
```

Comment: Try `:help empty()`